# What are the available 3rd party options to a) modify a templated word document b) convert a docx to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, pdf, docx

What are the available 3rd party options to

- (a) modify a templated word document
  (i.e., replacing values with those
  template fields in the docx file).
- (b) convert a docx to pdf

I've already implemented this using Primary Office InterOp and those COM Office components, however, the problem is that the component is going to be used under an ASP.NET app, and therefore, the Office itself cannot be installed on the server.

So, I'd like to know what are the available 3rd party options out there to handle such cases.

Any help would be highly appreciated,

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it myself, but you could try [Word Automation Services](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2009/10/26/introducing-word-automation-services.aspx).

Comment: This certainly adds another complexity to the system, i.e., the SharePoint Server 2010. I'd like to keep the minimum dependency. Any idea? (maybe a Web Service that exposes some interfaces, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago I worked on a project that had been built to use the [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) software. It was pretty easy to use and pretty powerful. It is definitely not free, but they do package the software so that you only buy the features you need.

Answer (score 0):

If money is no big deal, have a look at http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/

Answer (score 0):

(a) Use content control databinding (an OpenXML feature built into Word 2007 and later)

(b) docx4j IKVM'd as a DLL

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Open Office dot Org.  The conversion fidelity may not be perfect, but it will be Free.